# Conservation of momentum wrt center of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

"A person with mass m is sitting on one end of a lifeboat of uniform density. Mass of lifeboat is 3m. The person then walks a distance of L to the other side of the lifeboat. Which of the following statements best characterizes the motion of the lifeboat? "

1. The lifeboat shifts by the same distance traversed, but in the opposite direction of his motion.
2. The lifeboat shifts by L/4 in the opposite direction of the persons motion.
3. The lifeboat shifts in the same direction as the persons motion with constant velocity.
4. The lifeboat does not shift forward or backward as a result of the persons motion.

Specifically what I dont understand is what is actually happening in the problem. I know eq for center of mass but I dont know what principle or idea is being asked about when the person walks to the other side.

I think I can solve it if I know what is being asked of me so its more a matter of me not understanding the question. thanks

Comment: Your title should be improved: Right now, it carries very little information.

Comment: Hint: The question is about conservation of momentum, and what it implies for the motion of the center of mass.

Comment: I assume that both person and lifeboat are at rest first?

Comment: yup person and lifeboat at rest first. Thats actually whats confusing me. What should I assume happens when someone walks in boat on water? I know eq's for momentum and center of mass, but its the whole concept of walking in a boat thats confusing me.

Comment: i updated title, thanks for the momentum hint. Still not seeing it though

Answer (score 1):

When the person starts moving, the boat will start moving backward due to reaction. backward momentum = forward momentum. So, when the person stops, the process will reverse so that center of mass of the boat and of the person combined remains where it was before he started moving. The relative position of person will be now different inside the boat but the center of combined mass will remain unchanged. Ignoring the frictions etc.

As the center of combined mass with respect to the boat has shifted, the boat will move just enough so that the combined center remains where it was.